# How to set up parameters and arguments in Vuex mutations

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I am building a todo list app using Vue.js, Vuex, and Firebase. The app appears to work properly in that the Store file successfully manages the retrieval and rendering of the inputted todo items (to and from firestore). However, I still have a question about setting up parameters in Vuex. The REMOVE_TODO function in mutations (see store.js) seems to require two arguments, even though "id" is the only argument referenced in the actual code of the function. In other words, if I take out the initial argument, (in this case "state") then console will return an error that reads: "Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: a custom Object object". My question is: Why is this REMOVE_TODO function required to have two arguments to function properly, if the "id" argument is the only one actually used in the function? Why is having the other argument necessary? Here is my code below. Thanks!

app.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <input class="form-control" :value="newTodo" @change="getTodo" placeholder="I need to...">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addTodo">Add New Post</button>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="todo in this.$store.getters.getTodos" :key="todo.id">
            {{todo.title}}
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" @click="remove(todo.id)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Remove
                </button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  beforeCreate: function() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setTodo')
  },
  methods: {
    getTodo(event) {
      this.$store.dispatch('getTodo', event.target.value)
    },
    addTodo() {
      this.$store.dispatch('addTodo')
      this.$store.dispatch('clearTodo')
    },
    remove(id){
      this.$store.dispatch('removeTodo', id)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    newTodo() {
      return this.$store.getters.newTodo
    },
    todos(){
      return this.$store.getters.todos
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
li {
  margin: 10px;
}
</style>
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import db from '../firebase'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    todos: [],
    newTodo: '',
    errors: ''
  },
  mutations: { //syncronous, committed
    GET_TODO: (state, todo) => {
      state.newTodo = todo
    },
    ADD_TODO: state => {
      db.collection('items').add({
        title: state.newTodo,
        created_at: Date.now(),
      }).then(function(){
        console.log('Document successfully added')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.errors = error
      })
    },
    REMOVE_TODO: (state, id) => {
       if (id) {
         db.collection("items").doc(id).delete().then(function() {
           console.log('Document successfully deleted')
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           this.errors = error
         })
       } else {
         this.errors = 'Invalid ID'
       }
    },
    CLEAR_TODO: state => {
      state.newTodo = ''
    },
    SET_TODO: state => {
      let todos = []
      db.collection('items').orderBy('created_at').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        todos = []
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          todos.push({ id: doc.id, title: doc.data().title })
        })
        state.todos = todos
      })
    }
  },
  actions: { //asyncronous, dispatched
    getTodo: (context, todo) => {
      context.commit('GET_TODO', todo)
    },
    addTodo: context => {
      context.commit('ADD_TODO')
    },
    removeTodo: (context, id) => {
      context.commit('REMOVE_TODO', id)
    },
    clearTodo: context => {
      context.commit('CLEAR_TODO')
    },
    setTodo: context => {
      context.commit('SET_TODO')
    }
  },
  getters: {
    newTodo: state => state.newTodo,
    getTodos: state => {
      return state.todos
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi JS_is_awesome18 the but of mutation is to modify the state you must give it to update your state may be you can have a message attribut in state and do state.message = "document  deleted" if its ok or not state.message = "error document not deleted".https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html

Comment: @Birante, thanks for the feedback, though I'm not sure if that fully answers the question. Does this mean a function in mutation, by default, requires state as an argument even if state is not used in the code of the function?

Comment: Yes you understand everything i think its is a kind of best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really anything to do with Vuex, it's just how JavaScript function invocation works. Arguments are passed by position, not name.

You've got `REMOVE_TODO: (state, id) => {` but the names `state` and `id` are only really significant inside the function. Outside the function, from the caller's perspective, those names don't matter. It could just as easily be `REMOVE_TODO: (a, b) => {`.

When Vuex invokes the mutation it will pass the `state` object as the first argument and the `payload` as the second argument. Effectively it's calling:

```js
mutations.REMOVE_TODO(state, payload)
```

I reiterate that the names of the arguments don't actually matter, just their positions.

This is internal inside Vuex, not something you have direct control over. If you were calling the function yourself you could pass whatever you want but you aren't (nor should you be). Instead you are (quite rightly) calling `commit`. You pass the desired `payload` to `commit` and Vuex will then do the rest, calling the relevant mutation and passing it the `state` and `payload`.

Defining the function as `REMOVE_TODO: (id) => {` instead won't change the arguments that are passed by the caller. The first argument will still be the `state` object. You've named it `id` but that doesn't make any difference, it'll still be the `state` object.

In general, the problem with trying to drop the first argument is that all the other arguments effectively shuffle down, so the positions of the desired argument names no longer match the positions of the arguments that are passed. There's no such problem with dropping an argument from the end as the other arguments don't move positions. So if you just need the `state` but not the `payload` then you can just drop the second argument no problem. API designers always try to put optional arguments towards the end so that they can be dropped without causing any problems.

For a mutation, the `payload` can very easily be unnecessary but the `state` is always needed. The whole point of a mutation is to change the `state`. If you aren't changing the `state` then you shouldn't be using a mutation.

As noted in your code, `actions` are asynchronous whereas `mutations` need to be synchronous. But that isn't what you've got. Currently you have a lot of asynchronous calls to Firebase inside your mutations. All of that needs moving into the `actions`. Note that Promises are always asynchronous, so if you find yourself calling `then` inside a mutation you're doing it wrong. The only portion of this that should be inside the `mutations` is when you're modifying the `state`.

You also need to avoid using `this` within a Vuex store. You should find that everything you need is accessible from the arguments passed to the function. Currently you have `this.errors = error` and similar in your mutations. I'm assuming that should be `state.errors = error`.

**Update:**

As requested in the comments:

```js
SET_TODO (state, todos) {
  state.todos = todos
}
```

```js
setTodo ({commit}) {
  db.collection('items').orderBy('created_at').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const todos = []

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      todos.push({ id: doc.id, title: doc.data().title })
    })

    commit('SET_TODO', todos)
  })
}
```

Note that this makes no attempt to deal with possible race conditions.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. Could you perhaps provide an example of the store rewritten with the promise moved to the action? I am trying to reconfigure my store to reflect what you have written .then being incorrectly written in the mutation. If you could provide a snippet of code to show an example, that would be super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 Done.